# How to define size of class array parameter in source file?

Tags: c++, class, constants, member, extern

Imagine I have this class.

**Foo.hpp:**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

class Foo {
  static const std::size_t Size;
  std::uint32_t buffer[Size];
};
```

I want to calculate `Size` in the source file, so I don't need to include the files needed for the calculation in the header.

**Foo.cpp:**

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

#include "Lib1.hpp" // -> #define Size1 1
#include "Lib2.hpp" // -> #define Size2 2

const std::size_t Foo::Size = Size1 + Size2;
```

Doing so I get the following error:

```
In file included from src\Foo.cpp:1:
include/Foo.hpp:6:24: error: size of array 'buffer' is not an integral constant-expression
   30 |   std::uint32_t buffer[Size];
      |                        ^~~~
```

Is it possible to externaly declare a static const class member? If yes, how?

Comment: *"Is it possible to externaly declare a static const class member?"* Yes, you did it, but it's not going to be a compile-time constant in places where the definition isn't visible. Is just using `std::vector` an option? If you want to avoid heap allocation (which `std::vector` would use), the compiler needs to know the class size at compile-time, which isn't possible if the array size is hidden in a different translation unit).

Comment: what is `Size1` and `Size2` ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But why using a vector stored in heap if the size of array is a compile-time constant?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Size1 and Size2 are constants from the included files

Comment: Aha, I've just edited the comment to explain that, right before you asked. Remember that translation units are compiled independently. If the value is only known in one TU, the value by definition isn't a *compile*-time constant in other TUs.

Comment: @GURKE - The practical problem is that recompiling the cpp file cannot redo the `Size` in the header, perhaps already used by other files.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So in conclusion: It isn't possible. :( My idea is, I don't want to include Lib1 and Lib2 in the header file, because every file including Foo.hpp would also include Lib1 and Lib2 which isn't necessarry. If I could inlcude the libs only in the source, they wouldn't spam the namespace of all the other files...

Comment: `#define Size1 1`  is not at all what I have in mind when you say "...are constants". Details matter. If those headers only have one line that defines a preprocessor token, you should show those lines rather than writing a comment that explains how those line would look like. Details matter, and the more complete the code you show is the more likely it is that we can help

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That's why I had already expanded my code above...

Comment: @BoP That seems logical to me :/

Comment: my point is just that its better to show the code rather than writing a comment that describes the code. It would even be less to type. Instead of `#include "Lib1.hpp" // -> #define Size1 1` that line can be `#define Size1 1`. Though, no worries, the crux of the question is elsewhere and we know what you mean.

Comment: You might export `Size1` and `Size2` into one or two separate headers that then are included by the `LibN` headers (if you are under control of these). Then you can include these headers independently within `Foo.hpp` as well without including the library definitions.

Comment: In order to avoid include too many libraries header in your Foo header (and I see many good reason to do it), I think the more robust solution is to move the data in an dynamic allocated area: ```std::vector``` will make it. If you have to avoid dynamic allocation, the only solution I see is to regroup Size1, Size2, and the Foo::Size in a new (tiny) header shared accross the required files (even if I'm not in love with that solution, a static_assert to double check the sizes where required may help)

Comment: I am using an ESP8266. `Size1` and `Size2` are defined in the ESP-framework (defining the flash size). So I am not really under control of them. Also it does not really have that much heap. But, I have a other solution now: The class is a singleton, therefore I just moved the whole array out of the class into the source file and declared it static.